# How to grant connect and read/write permission to ALL databases?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, role

I want a SQL Server login that can READ, WRITE and View definition on all databases.

After doing:

```
USE master;
GRANT VIEW ANY Definition TO [a];
```

It looks like I have to GRANT CONNECT and read/write to each and every single database.

Isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You indeed have to add the user to the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles for each of your existing databases.

Such a query can be used for existing (and ONLINE) user databases:

```
DECLARE @user sysname = 'userTest1';
DECLARE @login sysname = 'userTest1';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '
    USE ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ';

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = ''' + @user + ''')
    BEGIN
        CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@user)
           + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@login)
           + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_change_users_login ''Update_One'', ''' + @user + ''', ''' + @login + ''';
    END

    EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''' + @user + ''';

    EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember ''db_datawriter'', '''+ @user + '''; 
'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4 AND state = 0;

--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
print @sql
```

- This will print the first 4000 chararacters from `@sql`. Comment out the EXEC line to execute it.
- The user is created if it does not exist or the link to the login is updated if the user is already there
- It then add the user to the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles
- Any other right or role needed can be added to the query

New databases are created from `model` and will inherit its setting.
The User can be added to the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles on model:

```
use model
go
CREATE USER [userTest1] FOR LOGIN [userTest1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'userTest1';
EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'userTest1';
```

The first query can take care of both `model` and user database using this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (database_id > 4 or name = 'model') AND state = 0;
```

Note (From Kenneth Fisher): With SQL Server 2014, there are some new permissions `CONNECT ANY DATABASE` and `SELECT ALL USER SECURABLES` that would cover the connect and read but unfortunately there is nothing similar yet for write permissions. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx))